# Connecting the domain obtained from godaddy to the service running in Google Cloud Run

Tags: serverless, google-cloud-run, domain-mapping

I bought a domain from godaddy for my service running on Gcr, for example: foo.com (I didn't know about the existence of Cloud Domains). In order to establish a domain relationship with my service, I first verified my domain over https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home

Then I added a record via Google cloud console -> Network Services - Cloud DNS and added the incoming records to my records in GoDaddy.

[image]

and when I check my Domain Name on https://dnschecker.org/, the results do not confirm the operation.
[image]

However, even though 16 hours have passed, my transaction is still not confirmed.
[image]
How can I confirm this domain? What is a wrong or missing transaction?

Comment: What's the TTL of your DNS record?

Comment: As mentioned in the point number 5 [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#dns_update), it can take upto 24 hours depending on the registrar and the [Time-To-Live(TTL)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090?hl=en#TTL) of your domain. As already mentioned by  guillaume blaquiere it is necessary to know the TTL value of your DNS record.

Comment: My TTL value is 1 hour

Comment: Is is still not confirmed?

Comment: @Prabir--> Now it seems that the gcr is verified, but when I go to the domain, it says the site cannot be reached with the message "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

Comment: I was able to view it from other devices a few times after it was approved, but now the error has become a permanent situation.

Comment: The `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error may occur due to the misconfiguration or due to the problem with the DNS. Can you check with the steps mentioned [here](https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/fix-dns_probe_finished_nxdomain) if that resolves the issue?

Comment: Hello, same problem here but can I ask what external IP address did you input upon creating your cloud DNS? @EnesKorkmaz

Comment: @CJCruz --> Since I am connecting to a container-based service, I cannot view external IP as in virtual machines.

Comment: @CJCruz --> My problem still continues. Do you know how I can reach the external IP of the container?

Comment: @Enes Korkmaz I've done it! But by using cloudrun only without vm. I mapped my domain via godaddy by following these steps https://medium.com/@sandymadaan/domain-mapping-in-gcp-1126a8d29202

Comment: @CJCruz --> Thank you very much for the reference. However, I have one more question. Are we going to delete the A and AAAA records given in the Update DNS mapping step, overwrite the records in godaddy, or add them under it?

Comment: Yes you do need to delete them (the default A and AAAA by godaddy). In my case, it worked after they got removed from my DNS.

Comment: @CJCruz--> it finally worked. thank you so much you ended a 21 day pain hahaha

Comment: @CJCruz-->Can you add your advice as an answer?

Comment: @CJCruz--> here was only one problem. I cannot access www.foo.com. I only have access to foo.com

Comment: got it done, it's simple. I just added a cname with the www name to my dns records.

Comment: @EnesKorkmaz I'm glad that it finally worked for you too haha. Alright I'll add it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it! But by using cloudrun only. I mapped my domain via godaddy by following these steps [medium.com/@sandymadaan/domain-mapping-in-gcp-1126a8d29202.](https://medium.com/@sandymadaan/domain-mapping-in-gcp-1126a8d29202)

**Note:**
Remove all the default A and AAAA in godaddy before putting all your DNS records from cloudrun